# How to scroll tableView to a newly added row that is not necessarily at the bottom or top?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, swift3, scroll

Well the title says it all. I am designing an app that takes input from user and adds the content into the table.

However, I am using priority awareness so if the user selects ‘Urgent’ priority then that task will be on the top etc
Obviously I am using sortdescriptor to sort the fetched data from Core Data.

As you can see from this pic (just a design), the input textview comes in view when keyboard is invoked and the tableview is in the background. When you select the priority and press the add button, the tableview should scroll to that area where the new row will be added.

I am using NSFetchedResultsController as well.

Any help on this will be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in the Xcode docs for UITableView on the string "Scroll" reveals the method `scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)`

The docs say:

> Scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is
>   at a particular location on the screen.

So if your table view is divided into sections, one for each priority, you would specify an indexPath for the section of the priority the user has selected.

Comment: That's a good idea. But the thing is I am not using sections. I am just using a sort descriptor to sort the fetched results in descending order. 
Also let me know how can I implement sections in this sort of setting?

Comment: So if you're not using sections then calculate the indexPath of the desired row and use that. As for how to implement a sectioned tableView, that's a separate question, and beyond the scope of an SO post. There should be tutorials explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tableview `scrollToRow` function to scroll to the newly added item

```
tableView.reloadData()
   
// Scroll to the newly added item
let lastRowIndex = IndexPath(row: itemArray.count - 1, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastRowIndex, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```